# No matching authentication protocol - connect ADW to private endpoint Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I created db-link on ADW based on OCI to private endpoint (without wallet) to Oracle DB 11.0.2 and I get error like: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

I tested the same solution on Oracle Database 19c based on OCI, create db-link to Oracle DB 11.0.2 and I get NO ERROR and db-link is working ok.

ADW and Oracle Database 19c have the same DB Version.

Why ADW has error while Oracle DB 19c get no erro?
What can I do on ADW to connect with Oracle DB 11.0.2?

Edit1:

'11.0.2' -- There is 11.2.0.1.
Oracle 19c on tradition install on Linux instance on OCI - and it's working. ADW on OCI - has error.

Comment: First, there is no Oracle 11.0.2. There is 11.2.0.1, 11.2.0.2, 11.2.0.3, and 11.2.0.4. Which are you running? Is your Oracle 19c database an ATP database, or is it a "traditional" install on a stand-along Linux instance?

Comment: Yes, sorry - my mistake. There is 11.2.0.1.

Comment: Oracle 19c on tradition install on Linux instance on OCI - and it's working. 
ADW on OCI - has error.

Comment: Best guess is that something on your traditional install is a little different than Oracle's configuration in ADW, even if they're both 19c. A 19c client should not be able to connect to an 11.2.0.1 server at all, based on Oracle's supported client/server compatibility matrix. Your server needs to be at a version of *at least* 11.2.0.4 to support a 19c client. The anomaly here is that your traditional server *works*, not that ADW doesn't.

Comment: @pmdba Ok, thanks information. Can suggest me how to migrate data form 11.2.0.1 to ADW in the simplest way?

Comment: Without direct connectivity, you'll probably have to use datapump to export/import your data. The *exact* method you use to do that will depend on your specific requirements for data availability and latency. I'd say upgrade your 11.2.0.1 server, but I doubt the patches to do that are available any more from Oracle given that you're at least 4 or 5 major generations of the database behind, *none* of which are supported any more.